# How easy is it to roll back a file that has been checked-in in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've (apparently) checked-in (added) a file that shouldn't have been added to a branch. I need to revert this, but since then, 20 or so changesets have been added to the repository.

I'm used to working with Subversion, where it's only a few clicks and it's out. How easy is it in TFS?

Comment: Can't you just delete the file and check in the deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS is a pain to use in general (personal and biased opinion). Here's a [how-to article from Microsoft on how to proceed to revert changes back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (warning: more than a few clicks away).

As given in that article, the steps to revert to a prior version of (a) file(s) are:

> 1. In Source Control Explorer, right-click the file whose changeset you want to roll back, and then click **Get specific version** on the
>      context menu.
> 2. In the **Get** dialog box, select the prior version of the file, and then click **Get**. For more information, see [How to: Retrieve
>      Old Versions of Files from
>      Changesets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181416(v=vs.80).aspx).
> 3. After this file is in your workspace, right-click the file, and then click **Check Out for Edit** on the context menu.
> 4. Right-click the file again, and then click **Check In Pending Changes**.
> 5. In the **Check In - Source Files** dialog box, select the file, and then click Check in.
>
>    The **Resolve Conflicts** dialog box appears.
> 6. Click **Resolve** to open the **Resolve version conflict** dialog box.
> 7. Select **Discard server changes**.
> 8. Click **OK**.
>
>    > NOTE: To review your decision before discarding the server changes, you can click **Compare** to view the server and local copies
>    >     simultaneously.
> 9. In the **Resolve Conflicts** dialog box, click **Close**.
> 10. In Source Control Explorer, right-click the file, and then click **Check In Pending Changes**.
> 11. In the **Check In - Source Files** dialog box, click **Check in**.

Comment: @lloydphillips, oh believe me, my arse hearts every day after using TFS and SharePoint intensively at work :-) Trying to limit the damage with GIT at home :-)

Comment: I've used a lot of source control systems over the years, and the thing I've noticed is that if I learned to use their prescribed approach, they were all pretty good. But if I tried to make them work "the way I wanted", I fought and hated them.

Comment: @Jason Williams, the problem is that after DVCS such as GIT were out TFS *prescribed approach* looks primitive to me (once again strictly personal opinion, not willing to influence anyone here).

Answer (score 1):

As @Darin has posted, you can simply Get the state of the previous version/changeset onto your PC and then check it in as a new version, thus undoing the effect of the check in. This is dead easy and can be done from the GUI, but does involve a fair bit of faffing around.

If you're happy to use the command line, you can also command TFS to [rollback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) the changeset for you. This does all the "work" of the above option, leaving you with a changeset in your pending changes that will undo the checkin's effect, but hopefully with a bit less effort.

Answer (score 0):

If it is *added* by mistake, you don't want to roll back.  Instead, you want to `tf destroy` (from the command line) that file in each of the branches.

TFS can be a bear to work with if you add a file, delete it, then re-add a new file with the same name.  It makes merging much more difficult.